# Can we use PrimaryCommandSurface in Outlook add-in generated by yo office

Tags: plugins, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, yo

Is there any way we can use PrimaryCommandSurface to show the add-in on the top Ribbon in the outlook add-in development, if yes Please help with the updated valid manifest.xml.

**If not help with the other way how to create outlook top Ribbon commands plug-in**

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
          <CustomTab id="Contoso Tab">
          <!-- If you want to use a default tab that comes with Office, remove the above CustomTab element, and then uncomment the following OfficeTab element -->
            <!-- <OfficeTab id="TabData"> -->
            <Label resid="residLabel4" />
            <Group id="Group1Id12">
              <Label resid="residLabel4" />
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_32x32" />
              </Icon>
              <Tooltip resid="residToolTip" />
              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button1Id1">

                  <!-- information about the control -->
              </Control>
              <!-- other controls, as needed -->
            </Group>
          </CustomTab>
        </ExtensionPoint>

      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
        <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuCell">
          <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="ContextMenu2">
                  <!-- information about the control -->
          </Control>
          <!-- other controls, as needed -->
        </OfficeMenu>
        </ExtensionPoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PrimaryCommandSurface` stands for the ribbon in Office. In case of Outlook we deal with read or compose items, so we should use the `MessageReadCommandSurface` for received items, for example:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
  <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
        <-- OfficeTab Definition -->
  </OfficeTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

The `TabDefault` is the `idMso` value of the built-in tab in Outlook.

Also you you can place controls into a custom tab in the following way:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
  <CustomTab id="TabCustom1">
        <-- CustomTab Definition -->
  </CustomTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

If you need to get a ribbon UI displayed for the composed items in Outlook you need to use the `MessageComposeCommandSurface` extension point that puts buttons on the ribbon for add-ins using mail compose form:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
  <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
        <-- OfficeTab Definition -->
  </OfficeTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

And to place controls into the custom tab:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
  <CustomTab id="TabCustom1">
        <-- CustomTab Definition -->
  </CustomTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

See the [ExtensionPoint element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint) for more information.

Comment: Is there any way we can create add which comes in the ribbon not in the compose or read item. Like we have zoom for meet?

Comment: There are other extension points like the `AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface` which puts buttons on the ribbon for the form that's displayed to the attendee of the meeting. Take a look at the article mentioned in my post for available extension points.

Comment: How can we create plugin like we have zoom for outlook ?

Comment: That is another question, so I'd suggest posting a new question separately.